# Registering a civil union blue card holder Germany

Tags: germany, immigration, blue-card, legal

I am going to Germany with a blue card, but the law in my country does not recognize us until there is a marriage. I want to bring my long-term girlfriend with me to live in Germany.

Can I as a blue card holder register a civil union with my foreign girlfriend while in Germany?

Comment: It would probably be better to contact the consulate before you leave and ask what form of proof would be needed to show that a long term relationship has existed. Collect documents that show that you both have lived at the same residence (rental contract, employment contracts with same address etc. ).

Answer (score 0):

Germany had something called an eingetragene Lebenspartnerschaft (registered civil union) from 2001 to 2017. It was an almost-but-not-quite marriage status for same-sex couples who were not allowed to marry at the time. This has been *replaced* in 2017 by the same-sex marriage.

So that is probably not what you want.